# How to set relative layout background to transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageButton`. I need to show only the `ImageButton` while running. Now its displaying the button including the `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context="com.austurn.raksha.raksha.MainActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pushme" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My screen view

[image]

Required screen

[Required screen-click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFhBq.jpg)

Comment: A `RelativeLayout` has no background by default. What in your screenshot do you think is the background of the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: This might taking default background color of Activity/Application theme. By default Relative layout does not have background.

Comment: Do you want to see the image behind it? its alpha is set to 0, remove that line

Comment: I need to show only the "push me" button while running. The white background should be transparent so that we can see the mobile screen..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show button on ImageView, Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context="com.austurn.raksha.raksha.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pushme" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks ramin, this is not what i required.. i need the background to be transparent. only the imagebutton to be visible while running.